# this.form.submit() not working after clicking div element in form

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, submit

I was trying to test form submission using mouse clicks but the form doesn't seem to submit with vanilla javascript.

I'm using this simple markup and code:

```
<form name="form" id="price" action="" method="post">
<div class="category" name="price" value="50 dollars" 
onClick="this.form.submit();"
>price</div>

</form>

<?php
echo $_POST['price'];

?>
```

I can submit the form with Jquery, but I don't understand why `this.form.submit()` is not working with vanilla javascript? I'm using Chrome to test this.

Comment: Div tag  can't containt attribute "value"

Comment: My answer should work with all major browsers. Please select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `div` is not a form element. There is no `this.form` for it.

You can still do `document.forms.form.submit()` (`.form` since you have `name="form"`)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was trying to see if I could reduce the markup  for forms using `div` instead of `input`

Comment: If that's all you're trying to accomplish, I'd recommend that you go with an `input` anyway, as it is built to be a form element.

Comment: There is a simpler a way to do this. See my answer below

Comment: @monarch: A matter of taste, perhaps, but relying on `parentNode` will mean your code will break if the markup changes. If you're doing something trivial like wrapping the submit button in another div, you might check whether the presentation is broken, but you wouldn't expect that change to break *functionality*. This solution will only break if the name of the form changes, and I'd argue its name is more inherently tied to its functionality. You wouldn't change that without thorough functionality tests.

Answer (score 4):

Your code might work if you tried something like this:

```
onClick="document.forms["price"].submit();"
```

`this` in your case actually refers to the `div` tag, not the document object which contains the reference to the form itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code if your form name is "filter-form"

```
onclick="return document.forms.filter-form.submit();"
```

Comment: That works, but a better way would be to use the parentNode attribute, as per my answer

Answer (score 0):

A `div` isn't a form element (thus no `.form` property) nor has it a value. I think you wanted `<input>` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: sometimes you do want/need to use a div.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but this should work

```
onclick="this.parentNode.form.submit()"
```

Comment: Not my down-vote, but I suspect it was because this _only_ works if there are no nesting markup between the **form** and the element with this attribute.  You could need **this.parentNode.parentNode.form.submit()** or worse.