# clicking on a div is not submitting form in Chrome on localhost

Tags: forms, google-chrome, localhost

I think I have found an interesting problem (at least to me). I have a form that uses a click on a div inside the form to submit. I have used "document.forms.form.submit()" to make the div clickable to submit as suggested here [this.form.submit() not working after clicking div element in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382184/this-form-submit-not-working-after-clicking-div-element-in-form) (thanks David Hedlund!)

However the form was working fine in chrome, ff. But for some unknown reason, running the form in localhost on chrome is not working now. ff is working fine. What makes the problem interesting is when I uploaded the form to a web-server it works in chrome! Any Idea why this is happening in local machine? I am using Xampp.

Here is the form-

```
<form name="form" action="login_process.php" method="POST">
<div>
  Username: <input style="width:100px;" name="login_client[]" type="text" />
  Password: <input style="width:100px;" name="login_client[]" type="password" />
</div>

<div  align="right" class="whitearial12" style="position:absolute;  font-size:10px; width:360px; height:17px; right:110px; top:35px;">
  Forgotten your <a href="#">password</a>, or need to <a href="#">register</a>? 
</div>
<!-- this is the div !-->
<div onClick="document.forms.form.submit()" align="center" class="whitearial12" style="cursor: pointer; position:absolute; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:-3px; width:80px; height:17px; right:20px; top:10px; background-image: url(Images/button_blank.png); background-repeat:no-repeat">
    Log In
</div>
</form>
```

Update: Let me add what I noticed further. This form is included in index.php file from another php file named header.php. I have tried running only the header.php. The form works alright in that case in chrome. But including it in index.php does not work.

Comment: Its a php file, it has to post back to a server and waits to recieve a response, if your localhost is not configured to process php files, the page will not work

Comment: well, I guess localhost is configured nicely as the same form works in firefox in localhost. :) The problem is clicking on the div is not submitting the form in chrome on localhost. thanks anyway for the reply :)

Comment: try something like this on your onClick = document.forms["form"].submit();

Comment: Tried that, not working.

Comment: it is not working it FF now. @Shouvik

Comment: It not working after you edited it to my code or did your code stop working on ff too?

Comment: yea, after replacing with your code it stopped working on FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest including jQuery and reworking to resemble this

```
<form id="MyForm" action="login_process.php" method="post">
    <span onclick="javascript:$('#MyForm').submit();">Magical ponies await</span>
</form>
```

Using jquery can help with cross-browser issues a lot, but if you can't do that, how about

```
<form id="XX" action="login_process.php" method="post">
  <span onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('XX').submit();">AVAST</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Ids are lovely as you often end up with a bunch of forms and need to target specific ones.

Comment: I think this might be usable for your other question as well, I'll add an answer there as well as I'm greedy! I saw there that you don't know how to use jquery, which is ok, but does the other method work for you? (btw, imho jquery is quite simple to use for basic things like in this example)