# Select box auto submit with php variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to create a self submitting select box that takes the user to a new page every time they select from the drop down. At the moment it doesn't do much of anything, just takes me to "//website.com/listing/?col=1&brand=" without any id to point it to the right url.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong please?

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
<? foreach($arrayCollection['brands'] as $id => $name):value ?>
    <option value="//website.com/listing/?col=1&brand=<?php echo $id; ?>">
       <?php echo $name; ?>
   </option>
<? endforeach; ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please refer to [this][1]. This might work:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8382197/1841760

Comment: you would like to re-direct the page based on `id` on onchange of selectbox?

Comment: you don't have **php** here : `<? foreach` and here: `<? endforeach;` is this typo or your real code?

Comment: well, these are short_tags! can be used but are harmful

Comment: @AspiringAqib may be this(short_tags!) is causing the propblem. if not activated in the php ini i think.

Comment: guess user posted n left the scene!

Answer (score 1):

**Since you've tagged in jquery:**

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <select id="selectDropDown">
    <? 
    $arrayCollection['brands'] = array(0=>'zero',1=>'first',2=>'second',3=>'three',4=>'four');
    foreach($arrayCollection['brands'] as $id => $name):value ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
           <?php echo $name; ?>
       </option>
    <? endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    </form>
    <script>
    $('#selectDropDown').change(function(){
    window.location= '//website.com/listing/?col=1&brand='+$(this).val();
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
<?php foreach($arrayCollection['brands'] as $id => $name):value ?>
//^^^---------------------missed it
    <option value="//website.com/listing/?col=1&brand=<?php echo $id; ?>">
       <?php echo $name; ?>
   </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
//^^^---------------------missed it
</select>
</form>
```

might be useful foreach doc: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php